# Из субдомена в алиас

Tags: apache, nginx

Вы можете подсказать, как можно реализовать на Apache или nginx.
Существует субдомен admin.site.ru (находится в каталоге /home/admin/web/admin.site.ru/public_html), необходимо настроить сервер так, чтобы этот сайт был открыт по ссылке site.ru/admin / (/home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html)

Comment: есть гораздо больше одного способа сконфигурировать это, так что для упрощения задачи отвечающего лучше показать как сейчас сконфигурирована отдача с обоих доменов

Comment: да, пока к серверу нет доступа. Просто нужно, чтоб некоторые страницы с админки индексировались поисковиком с сайта. Хотя есть связь уже с таким расположением, в виде 'admin.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] и еще есть прямые ссылки, вот и думаю как бы реализовать чтоб потом не поломалось все. Тоесть по сути нужно зеркало.